# How to prevent run SKAction on paused scene (after unpaused), texture of node not change after pause/unpause scene

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, sprite-kit

I have two problems with pausing and unpausing scene. I have button:

```
    playPause = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "buttPause.png")
    playPause.name = "pause"
    playPause.setScale (0.65)
    playPause.position = CGPoint(x: -self.frame.width / 2.55 , y: self.frame.height / 2.27)
    playPause.zPosition = 10

    self.addChild(playPause)
```

I have set function to pause and unpause scene + change texture of button:

```
func buttonpauseplayTouched() {

    if isPlaying {
        playPause.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "buttPlay")
        isPlaying = false
        self.scene?.view?.isPaused = true
    }

    else {
        playPause.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "buttPause")
        isPlaying = true
        self.scene?.view?.isPaused = false
    }

}
```

I have set touch on button:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        location = touch.location(in: self)
        node = self.atPoint(location)
        if node.name == "pause" {

            buttonpauseplayTouched()



        }
        else {print ("Blank space")}
    }

}
```

Now when I touch pause button, I can pause and unpause scene, but texture not change? What is wrong? Or if I want to add other spritekitnode to scene when is paused, I can not.

Second problem is, that I have some other SKSpriteNodes on scene and I have set action when I touch them. If I touch them while scene is paused, nothing happen, but when I unpause scene, action on object run. How to prevent, when is scene paused, that I cannot perform action on object. I try :

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
for touch in touches {
    location = touch.location(in: self)
    node = self.atPoint(location)
    if node.name == "pause" {

        buttonpauseplayTouched()



    }
    else if scene?.view?.isPaused == true && node.name == "object" {print ("Nothing!!")}
    }
    else {print ("Blank space")}
}

}
```

Without success. Thanks for any tip.

UPDATE:

Thanks both of you again!
Solution with layers is better, I try it and it works fine! One little problem is with moving background:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
   createBackground()
  }
 func createBackground(){
    for i in 0...3 {
        background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background1.png")
        background.name = "background"
        background.setScale(0.694)
        background.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: CGFloat(i) * background.size.height)
        background.zPosition = 1


        gameLayer.addChild(background)
    }
}
func moveBackground(){

    gameLayer.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "background", using: ({
        (node, error) in

        node.position.y -= 7

        if node.position.y < -((self.background.size.height)) {
            node.position.y += (self.background.size.height) * 3

        }

    }))

}
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    moveBackground()
}
```

When I pause gameLayer, background still moving. How to edit code to stop move bacground when is gameLayer paused? I hope that only little change of code solve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put my controls on their own layer (SKNode) controlsLayer.addChild(pauseButton) and game objects on their own layer "gameLayer" then when I want to pause the game, I just pause the gameLayer (gameLayer.isPaused = true). This stops the game objects from moving, gives the appearance of being paused but still allows me to things like actions, add objects etc.

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    if !gameLayer.isPaused {
        moveBackground()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Solution with layers is exactly what I looking for. I´ve update my question because I have problem with moving background. Thanks for any tip.

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how to pause the background

Answer (score 1):

I am personally a fan of what Ron said, but just want to show you how you can do this in a few lines:

```
func buttonpauseplayTouched() {

  playPause.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: isPaused ? "buttonPlay" : "buttonPause")
  //pausing the scene rather than a view
  self.isPaused = !self.isPaused
}
```

So, basically, based on scene's `isPaused` property, you choose a texture. And after that, you toggle scene's paused property. You don't need `isPlaying` variable in this case.

Comment: Thanks! I try both solutions and works fine! But solution with layers is better, like you said. I,ve update my question because of moving bacground. Thanks of any tip.