# Paused layer come unpause after start app from background

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have set play/pause button to gameLayer - here: [How to prevent run SKAction on paused scene (after unpaused), texture of node not change after pause/unpause scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42935004/how-to-prevent-run-skaction-on-paused-scene-after-unpaused-texture-of-node-no)

Everything works fine, but I'm helpless with app on background. When I pause gameLayer and app goes to background or when I lock device, after app going to foreground, game layer is automatically unpause. How to prevent this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just listen for a UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification in your scene and take an appropriate action (pause gameLayer). If you are still stuck, let me know and I will write an answer for you.

Comment: I check apple documentation and found only `static let UIApplicationDidBecomeActive: NSNotification.Name` but I don't know how to exactly use it. Example will be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is what worked for me:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var gameLayer = SKNode()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(GameScene.pause),
                                               name: .UIApplicationDidBecomeActive,
                                               object: nil)
        let moveUp = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 100, duration: 2)
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveUp, moveUp.reversed()])
        let loop = SKAction.repeatForever(sequence)

        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(color: .purple, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))

        addChild(gameLayer)
        gameLayer.addChild(sprite)

        sprite.run(loop)
    }

    func pause(){

        gameLayer.speed = 0
    }

    override func willMove(from view: SKView) {
        super.willMove(from: view)

        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self,
                                                  name: .UIApplicationDidBecomeActive,
                                                  object: nil)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        gameLayer.speed = gameLayer.speed == 0 ? 1 : 0
    }
}
```

I haven't had time to test more, but I was expecting that something like this:

```
 func pause(){
        gameLayer.isPaused = true
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
       gameLayer.isPaused = !gameLayer.isPaused
    }
```

would work, but surprisingly it isn't (the node continued with moving after the `pause()` method was executed). I don't really know if this is a bug or a feature :) but IMHO, I would say it is a bug. Anyways, you can achieve what you want using the speed property. Just copy and paste this code to see how it works.

Comment: Maybe some people like @Knight0fDragon or @AlessandroOrnano might help with explaining why `isPaused` doesn't work in this case though... Maybe I am just missing something because of brief testing, but it seems like a bug.

Comment: And one side note... Because `UIApplicationDidBecomeActive` notification is fired at very start of application, `gameLayer` will be paused from the beginning. So you have to tap the screen to unpause the action that moves a sprite up and down...

Comment: the `isPaused` line definitely works I copied your code and it worked as expected. Weird thing though, the Notifications wouldn't fire

Comment: @RonMyschuk Hi Ron, thanks for taking a look at this. `isPaused` works for me as well in `touchesBegan`. Also, notifications are fired correctly. But, as I mentioned, somehow, changing `isPaused` property inside of `pause()` method doesn't have an effect. Can you please confirm, by putting a breakpoint inside of `pause()` method, that it is not executed when you return from background?

Comment: I had tried that already, but nothing. I've never used this particular notification before, and I've rarely used these notifications in the past. Maybe I'm setting it up wrong. I set it up like you have in your code, but do I need to be doing this in the AppDelegate? I am curious as to what is happening here as well

Comment: Nope, no code in AppDelegate is required. Only this code I have posted. @RonMyschuk. A scene should listen for these notifications and respond to them...

Comment: ok, it's only 8 in the morning here...I need some coffee. I'll recreate this project as a new project and get back with my findings

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138952/discussion-between-ron-myschuk-and-whirlwind).

Answer (score 0):

I've made a maybe not that beautiful, but a very easy workaround.

Just added `var gamePaused = false` to the Scene class, which is set to true in pause(), and then in

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) { 
    guard gamePaused == false else {
        if playLayer.isPaused == false {playLayer.isPaused = true}
        return
    }
.....
}
```

So each time the app start from the background, the playLayer.isPaused is set to true just with the first rendered frame.